# Charting tool that generate on memory

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, reporting-services, charts

My question seems confusing but I'll let you explain it more clearly. Me and my team we're currently developing a complex report that comprises of words, tables and charts. As of now we generate this report by using a word document template and filling it up with the model we have. As for chart this is where it becomes complicated, we have two application that we're using in business one is a windows/wpf application and a web application. Both application uses the same engine we have for generating chart (ComponentOne) but the engine itself is only compatible for windows application. We use the assembly we generate from windows/wpf application on our web application for us to generate a report.

Our report generator on website will only have filter and parameters on what kind of report they want to generate and on a press of button. What do you think will be the best to tackle this issue so that we can drop using the assembly we have. We don't like to drop using template for this as these greatly help us on maintaining the report when changes is required the only thing that we think right now on how can we generate a chart on memory and convert it into an image so that we can dump it on our template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not confusing, it's just not clear at all. If I get it right you just have a reporting tools ComponentOne that make reports on software side and it's not adapated for web side.

You somewhat tried to tackle it by using software dll in your website and it doesn't work as well as you expected/wanted. And you keep trying as of now.

Your question is basicly "How can I use a dll designed for software into a website?"

**And the answer is simple.** It's case by case when not outright impossible.

I invite you to look for another solution than using a software designed dll on a website. Even your idea of putting it inside an image is somewhat bad (lose of all controllers / defeat of the purpose of an interactive report.)

I'm pretty sure that ComponentOne would have think of such a problem as web reports and maybe even a solution to link web reports to soft reports. With a little search, I found a [C1WebReport](http://www.componentone.com/newimages/Products/Documentation/ASPNET.WebReport.pdf) and even found [some forums talking about C1Report to C1WebReport](http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/c1report-to-c1webreport-help/). Does it answer your problem?